# careers.stackoverflow.com linked to the wrong github account

Tags: support, jobs, github

I recently signed up for careers.stackoverflow.com and it linked to my work github.com account and not my personal one.  Problem is that I can't relink it back to my personal github.com account.

I don't have any open source stuff with my work github.com account so careers.stackoverflow.com's linking to it serves no point.  Can I be unlinked?

Comment: Sure, though I don’t know which is yours. Send a note to matt@stackoverflow.com with a link to your profile. Thanks!